# How to, in Python3, make the typing system know a subclass instance created by `super().*` method has subclass methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, mypy, class-method

```
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='A')

class A:

    @classmethod
    def create(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cls()


class B(A):

    def do(self):
        ...
    @classmethod
    def create(cls):
        obj = super().create()
        obj.do()
        #   ^^  <- complaint


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B.create()  # OK, no error
```

In the above example, the type-checker complains about `do` method invocation in the subclass `create` method. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Why do you write `bound='Parent'` when the parent class is named `A`?

Comment: @joel At runtime, `obj` is in fact an instance of `B`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a type hint on `B.create` seems to do the trick, even with strict options of mypy enabled

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T', bound='A')
U = TypeVar('U', bound='B')


class A:

    @classmethod
    def create(cls: Type[T]) -> T:
        return cls()


class B(A):

    def do(self) -> None:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def create(cls: Type[U]) -> U:
        obj = super().create()
        obj.do()
        return obj


if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B.create()
```

Comment: @joel mypy does complain on their code when running with the `--strict` flag (reproducible on mypy playground through options menu)