# Why is cls() allowed in Python mypy?

Tags: python, mypy, typing

Why is `cls()` accepted by mypy in

```
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="A")

class A:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls: type[T]) -> T:
        return cls()
```

If I subclass `A` with a different `__init__` signature,

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        super().__init__()
        self.a = a

B.create()
```

It still passes mypy (which I don't think it should), but at runtime I get

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'a'
```

as expected.

(this question is based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73441555/how-to-in-python3-make-the-typing-system-know-a-subclass-instance-created-by) but here I'm asking why no error rather than why error)

Comment: When type-checking `A`, there's no way to know what classes will inherit from it and what their `__init__()` signatures will be. This is dynamic and can't be checked by a static type checker.

Comment: Can you update the question to make it clear that you are definitely expecting the `TypeError` that you report.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, so the question is why MyPy doesn't say something like *"Type error: cls may not have a compatible constructor signature"*. It's true that type checkers can't recognise *all* type-safe code, but generally that means they reject any code that might be unsafe, not only code that is definitely unsafe.

Comment: @Barmar what @kaya3 said. I'd also add that subclassing and changing the `__init__` signature is an extremely common thing to do in python. Also that I believe there are ways to write this, using e.g. `Callable[[], T]` that are type safe

Comment: I wonder if it's related to the fact the argument 'a' is positional and the first error that's found is that it's missing. If it was there but of the wrong type I'm sure you'd get the response you were expecting.

Comment: If it warned about this, it would essentially have to warn about calling all `type[T]` variables, since you can never know whether some subclass changes the `__init__` signature.

Comment: @Barmar yes, and I believe it should. After all, it's not safe - it can fail at runtime mypy or not. And there is an alternative. I've noticed for a while now that people frequently and erroneously call a `type[T]`