# Python type hinting: Inherited class with different init

Tags: python, inheritance, mypy, typing, pylance

I can't figure out how to use type hint in Python when I have subclass with different parameters.

```py
class VehicleBase:

    def __init__(self, vehicle_type: str) -> None:

        self.vehicle_type: str = vehicle_type


class Car(VehicleBase):

    def __init__(self) -> None:

        super().__init__(vehicle_type="Car")
```

And I have a class to register a vehicle with parameter type of VehicleBase. But because I am passing init value in subclass, Pylance sees here an error:

```py
class RegisterVehicle:

    def __init__(vehicle: t.Type[VehicleBase]) -> None:

        self.vehicle = vehicle()
        # Argument missing for parameter "vehicle_type"
```

Any advice on this? Thank you.

Comment: You're missing `self` for `RegisterVehicle`. It's also not clear what the issue is here: `VehicleBase` expects a string, you are giving it no arguments. This *should* be an error.

Comment: `vehicle_type` is redundant; the fact that something is an instance of `Car` *already* indicates that the instance is a car.

Comment: It's fine to *add* arguments to `__init__`; it's usually a symptom of bad design if you think you need to *drop* an argument accepted by the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

This should be an error because `VehicleBase` expects a `str`, but I understand why you ask. You want to do e.g. `RegisterVehicle(Car)`, right? You may want `Callable[[], VehicleBase]`.

For the same reasons I mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73450054/5986907), it's unsafe more often than not to use `Type`/`type` in type hints. `Callable` is safer.